# RecyclerView Duplicating On Back Press in the Nested Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nested, back

**I create a nested recyclerView in my android project but when i am in the 2nd recyclerview and press back button in order to hide the keyboard. The Item of 2nd group automatically gets added at the end of 1st group.**

[image: When Back button is not pressed]

[image: When back button is pressed Coca-Cola 330nl CAM 24 is duplicated in group 2000ml]

**Adapter for first Recycler View..**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.hrisv001.OutletOrdersSKUWiseActivity;
import com.example.hrisv001.R;
import com.example.hrisv001.api.OutletList;
import com.example.hrisv001.api.SKUList;
import com.example.hrisv001.api.SKU_Brands_List;
import com.example.hrisv001.utils.SqlLiteHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SKUListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SKUListAdapter.HolderView>{

    private List<SKUList> skulist;
    private List<SKU_Brands_List> sku_brands_lists=new ArrayList<>();
    Item_List_Adapter adapter;
    private Context context;
    public static SqlLiteHelper sqlLiteHelper;



    public SKUListAdapter(List<SKUList> skulist,Context context)
    {
        this.skulist=skulist;
        this.context=context;
        setHasStableIds(true);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SKUListAdapter.HolderView onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layout= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sku_wise_list_style,parent,false);
        context=parent.getContext();
        return new HolderView(layout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final SKUListAdapter.HolderView holder, final int position) {
        holder.txt_sku_name.setText(skulist.get(position).getSKUName());
        final RecyclerView list_itemname_sku=holder.list_itemname;
        final LinearLayout ll_itemlist=holder.ll_skuname;
        sqlLiteHelper=new SqlLiteHelper(context,"SLMG_EMS.sqlite",null,1);
        final SQLiteDatabase databaseabplhee=sqlLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        holder.cview_step1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                for (int i=0;i<skulist.size();i++)
                {
                    if (i!=position)
                    {
                        ll_itemlist.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                }


                if (skulist.get(position).getExpanded() == null || skulist.get(position).getExpanded() == false) {
                    if (skulist.get(position).getValueAdded() == null || skulist.get(position).getValueAdded() == false) {
                        sku_brands_lists.clear();
                        String query = "SELECT DISTINCT(ITEMID) AS ITEMIDD,ITEMNAME,MRPCOST FROM TB_SKU_WISE_ITEMS WHERE PACKSIZE='" + skulist.get(position).getSKUName().trim() + "'";
                        Cursor cursor = databaseabplhee.rawQuery(query, null);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();

                        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

                            sku_brands_lists.add(new SKU_Brands_List(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ITEMIDD")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ITEMNAME")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MRPCOST")), 0.0));
                            cursor.moveToNext();
                        }

                        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(
                                list_itemname_sku.getContext(),
                                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
                                false
                        );
                        skulist.get(position).setValueAdded(true);
                        list_itemname_sku.setHasFixedSize(true);
                        list_itemname_sku.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                        adapter = new Item_List_Adapter(sku_brands_lists, context);
                        list_itemname_sku.setAdapter(adapter);
                        ll_itemlist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        skulist.get(position).setValueAdded(true);

                    } else {
                        ll_itemlist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    skulist.get(position).setExpanded(true);
                } else {
                    if (skulist.get(position).getValueAdded() == true) {
                        ll_itemlist.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        skulist.get(position).setExpanded(false);
                    }
                }
            }



        });
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return skulist.size();
    }

    class HolderView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView txt_sku_name;
        LinearLayout ll_skuname;
        RecyclerView list_itemname;
        CardView cview_step1;

        HolderView(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            cview_step1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.cview_step1);
            txt_sku_name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_sku_name);
            ll_skuname=itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_skuname);
            list_itemname=itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_itemname);

        }

    }
}
```

**Adapter for first Recycler View..**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.hrisv001.ItemOpeningClosingActivity;
import com.example.hrisv001.OutletOrdersSKUWiseActivity;
import com.example.hrisv001.R;
import com.example.hrisv001.api.SKUList;
import com.example.hrisv001.api.SKU_Brands_List;
import com.example.hrisv001.utils.AppConstants;
import com.example.hrisv001.utils.SqlLiteHelper;

import java.util.List;

public class Item_List_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Item_List_Adapter.HolderView> {

    List<SKU_Brands_List> sku_brands_lists;
    private Context context;
    public static SqlLiteHelper sqlLiteHelper;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    String empid;



    public Item_List_Adapter(List<SKU_Brands_List> sku_brands_lists,Context context)
    {
        this.sku_brands_lists=sku_brands_lists;
        this.context=context;
        setHasStableIds(true);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Item_List_Adapter.HolderView onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View layout= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.brand_wise_list_style,parent,false);
        return new HolderView(layout);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Item_List_Adapter.HolderView holder, final int position) {
            holder.tv_itemid.setText(sku_brands_lists.get(position).getITEMID());
            holder.tv_brand_name.setText(sku_brands_lists.get(position).getITEMNAME());
             holder.tv_brand_rate.setText(sku_brands_lists.get(position).getMRPCost());
            final EditText itemqty_qty=holder.et_itm_quantityy;

        holder.et_itm_quantityy.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                OutletOrdersSKUWiseActivity itmop;
                itmop = new OutletOrdersSKUWiseActivity();
                itmop.deleteNinsertItemToTable(holder.tv_itemid.getText().toString(),holder.tv_brand_rate.getText().toString(),itemqty_qty.getText().toString(),holder.tv_brand_name.getText().toString());



            /*

                sqlLiteHelper.DeleteLikeFromItemQtyList(holder.tv_itemid.getText().toString());
                try {
                    sqlLiteHelper.insertSKUWiseItemQtyList(holder.tv_itemid.getText().toString(),Double.parseDouble(holder.tv_brand_rate.getText().toString()),Double.parseDouble(itemqty_qty.getText().toString()));
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
*/
               /* double itemqtyy=0;
                if (itemqty_qty.getText().toString().trim().equals(null)||itemqty_qty.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
                {
                    itemqtyy=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    itemqtyy=Double.parseDouble(itemqty_qty.getText().toString());
                }
                sku_brands_lists.get(position).setQty(itemqtyy);*/
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return sku_brands_lists.size();
    }



    class HolderView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView tv_brand_name,tv_itemid,tv_brand_rate;
        EditText et_itm_quantityy;

        HolderView(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            tv_brand_name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_brand_name);
            tv_itemid=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_itemid);
            tv_brand_rate=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_brand_rate);
            et_itm_quantityy=itemView.findViewById(R.id.et_itm_quantityy_itemwise);
        }

    }
}
```